# Mysql Store Procedures

Tags: mysql

i am using MySQL store procedures
i want to fetch all rows with where clause
this is my query

```
Begin
select * from track_log
where activity_code = tr_code
and
lights = 'working' and fixtures = 'perfect' and artwork = 'present';
END
```

this get only one row

Comment: could you provide some sample data, the expected results, and the results you are getting?

Comment: Perhaps only one row meet the criteria

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want all rows fetch in mysql store procedure with where clause

Comment: Yes i have more than one row that meets this criteria.